# Show Different content to different users of same post

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

Suppose https://example.com/how-to-learn-seo is a post which is published and i want it to show this post content only to bots (google, bing, etc.) not to users. If a user visit then they will see a custom text (may be 404 but the url is same) and if google bot visits then they will see the original content of the post. I don't know how to achieve, anyone can help me to do this using htaccess or if you have another method.

Comment: This is referred to as [cloaking](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/cloaking), and not a good idea to do:  `Cloaking is considered a violation of Google's Webmaster Guidelines because it provides our users with different results than they expected.`